# Apache Nifi ExecuteSQL Processor - commands ignored until the end of transaction using Postgresql (but same query works in PgAdmin)

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, apache-nifi

I've been struggling lately to solve this issue - I have a large postgresql query that is being used to create orders in a postgres DB via an ExecuteSQL processor in Apache Nifi. The query involves an IF statement enclosed in a DO - BEGIN - END transaction. This is the ExecuteSQL version of the query (hence $$$$ instead of $$):

```
DO $$$$
BEGIN
    IF ( MULTIPLE CONDITIONS ) THEN
        
---MULTIPLE INSERT AND UPDATE STATEMENTS
        
    END IF;
END $$$$;
```

After substituting the ${} variables in the Nifi version of the query with the actual values from the previous processor EvaluateJSONPath, the ExecuteSQL processor attempts to run the final query:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF ( MULTIPLE CONDITIONS ) THEN
    
--- MULTIPLE INSERT AND UPDATE STATEMENTS    
        
    END IF;
END $$;
```

This query keeps leading to the following error via Nifi's ExecuteSQL -

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

But when I run the exact same query (copied from Nifi's Bulletin Board consisting of the entire query and error) in PgAdmin, the transaction is executed successfully without any errors. Does anyone have any clue what might be happening here and what I need to change for the ExecuteSQL processor? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There should be a cause error in log just before or after the error that you see in nifi UI. Please provide error records from log.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here's a bigger description of the error only being produced in the Bulletin board - for FlowFile[filename=RENAISSANCE AUG 2022 8.3.22.csv] due to org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block.
- Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid transaction termination
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 18 at ROLLBACK; routing to failure: {} 
And I can confirm that there is no ROLLBACK command being used at all throughout the entire query. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the data.

Comment: Can you check whether autocommit is turned on/off in pgAdmin and for the ExecuteSQL?